# I need to add a sentinel 2 image into Google Earth Engine Explorer graphical user interface

Tags: sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-explorer

I am using the graphical user interface of Google Earth Engine (Explorer) to carry out classification of land cover using sentinel 2. My study site is somewhere in Kenya with an id:

```
S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_EPA__20150914T075319_20160317T153700_A001190_T37MDU_N02_01_01
```

However, the format required is:

```
COPERNICUS/S2/20151128T002653_20151128T102149_T56MNN
```

and so I attempted to truncate my id to:

`COPERNICUS/S2/20150914T074233_20150914T074233_T37MDU`

It is still not being accepted by Earth Engine graphical user interface.

Answer (score 2):

A Sentinel-2 product name is composed of the acquisition date in the first place and the ingestion date in second place. When a reprocessing takes place the second date will change.

The image available in EarthEngine you are looking for has the ID `COPERNICUS/S2/20150914T074233_20160713T021501_T37MDU`

To use it as an image in EarthEngine:

```js
var kenyaSentinel2 = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2/20150914T074233_20160713T021501_T37MDU")
```

Also note, that there's a slight difference in acquisition date (measured at the start of the swath).

To make sure you find the image the easiests way would be to select a polygon for your region and filter the ImageCollection by polygon as well as date, to only show scenes from 2015-09-14.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response. However, the image whose id you have given me is not overlaying with the area that I am working in. What could be the reason for this? It is falling next to my area of interest.

Comment: It is located in the same Sentinel-2 grid zone as the reference you have given `T37MDU`. You might need to check if this is the correct grid tile with the [Sentinel-2 tiling grid KML](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products).

Comment: Ok great. Will do.

Comment: And how would you check if your desired image is available in Google's repository at all? I have tried multiple string manipulation and I always get `Image asset not found`.

Comment: @adamczi Do you already know the image you are looking for? As the filename contains the date you could apply `filterDate` or filter the Sentinel-2 ImageCollection by metadata such as `GRANULE_ID`.

Comment: @Kersten, I actually work on Landsat imagery and hoped there is a general tool. I have Surface Reflectance product that should be available and its filename is LC082140032014071501T1-SC20170531141651. I am able to load raw image from where the SR comes from, but since regular user cannot process to SR easily and USGS publish ready SR scenes, I hoped to get these.

Comment: @adamczi That sounds like a completely different question to me. Maybe open a new one if it has not been answered yet?

Comment: @Kersten, I received an answer on [GoogleGroup of EE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-earth-engine-developers/8KMOfZUcnZ8) - the L8 SR for C1 is not ready yet. Sorry for a mess here.